# grep prefix python strings

Tags: python

I'm having problems using findall in python.

I have a text such as:

`the name of 33e4853h45y45 is one of the 33e445a64b65 and we want all the 33e5c44598e46 to be matched`

So i'm trying to find all occurrences of of those alphanumeric strings in the text. the thing is I know they all have the "33e" prefix.

Right now, I have `strings = re.findall(r"(33e+)+", stdout_value)` but it doesn't work.
I want to be able to return `33e445a64b65, 33e5c44598e46`

Comment: what's wrong with 33e4853h45y45?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
>>> x="the name of 33e4853h45y45 is one of the 33e445a64b65 and we want all the 33e5c44598e46 to be matched"
>>> re.findall("33e\w+",x)
['33e4853h45y45', '33e445a64b65', '33e5c44598e46']
```

Comment: In case if you think that worked, you may want to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight variation:

```
>>> string = '''the name of 33e4853h45y45 is one of the 33e445a64b65 and we want all the 33e5c44598e46 to be matched'''
>>> re.findall(r"(33e[a-z0-9]+)", string)
['33e4853h45y45', '33e445a64b65', '33e5c44598e46']
```

Instead of matching any word characters, it will only match digits and lowercase numbers after the `33e` -- that's what the `[a-z0-9]+` means.

If you wanted to also match capital letters, you could replace that part with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead.